# Is there a way to free the memory used by threads when debugging in Android?

Tags: debugging, memory-leaks, bitmap, garbage-collection

I'm having some problems debugging an Android app which runs a string of memory-intensive operations on bitmaps. From Google's [Debugging tips](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/index.html#tips), I know that

> The debugger and garbage collector are currently loosely integrated. The VM guarantees that any object the debugger is aware of is not garbage collected until after the debugger disconnects. This can result in a buildup of objects over time while the debugger is connected. For example, if the debugger sees a running thread, the associated Thread object is not garbage collected even after the thread terminates.

Unfortunately, this means that while my app runs fine in release mode, any memory-intensive thread running in debug mode will be ignored by the garbage collector and be kept around so more and more memory is used as more and more memory-intensive threads are created, resulting in the app crashing because it fails to allocate the required memory.

Is there any way to explicitly tell the garbage collector that these threads should be collected, or some other way around this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this by spawning an `AsyncTask` rather than a `Thread`. It seems that AsyncTasks are cleared up more readily by the garbage collector and hence I was able to run the app in debug mode without issue.

An AsyncTask is the recommended way of spawning background operations. Any work to be done in the background should be placed in the task's `doInBackground(Params...)` method. AsyncTasks are usually intended to perform actions on the UI thread after completion, but you can avoid disturbing the UI thread by simply leaving the `onPostExecute(Result)`method empty or not present.